# Redis connection (in Doctrine cache) gets initialized on each command

Tags: symfony, redis, doctrine

I have a Symfony 4.1 app, where I use Doctrine and want to setup Redis cache for Doctrine.

Here is a part of `composer.json`

```
"snc/redis-bundle": "^2.1",
"symfony/doctrine-bridge": "^4.1",
"symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "^4.1",
```

Here is `yml` config file:

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        doctrine_cache:
            type: phpredis
            alias: doctrine_cache
            dsn: '%my_dsn%'
    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: doctrine_cache
            entity_manager: default
```

The problem is: on the very first time when Symfony tries to generate cache for all DI containers, it initializes Redis connection. This means for example when I run *any* console command, it tries to connect to redis. Example:

```
// very first command after git clone and composer install
php bin/console about
```

Output:

```
In PhpredisClientFactory.php line 64:
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

I expect that Redis cache service will be initialized lazily, otherwise I cannot run other build commands on independent (non having Redis) environment.
Can someone advise please?

Answer (score 0):

If this happens after `composer install` then you might have composer run the default commands:

```
 - "post-install-cmd"
 - "post-update-cmd"
```

Try to remove them and add see if the Redis works... If it works then add a script to your deployment entrypoint to run them at the end.

PS: pay attention to doctrine and Redis if you are using migrations: then you should also clear doctrine cache.